# Redirect parent as child window closes, without adding code to child

Tags: javascript

Alright, I am working on a site that displays third party developed courses, so I can't change anything in the actual pop-up window at all and the redirect call has to come from the parent window. The parent, child, and the redirectLocation are all on the same server, so that shouldn't be an issue. Here is the code I want to work.

```
    var new_window = window.open('courseAddress.php')

    new_window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        popupClosing(); 
    }

    function popupClosing(){
        window.location ="redirectLocation.php";
        alert('The popup has closed!');
        return false;
    };
```

The alert is firing, but the parent window doesn't seem to refresh. If I put the `window.location ="redirectLocation.php";` outside of the .onbeforeunload the refresh works just fine.

I am sure I am missing something simple. Thank you in advance. I have read the other issue like this on here, however they were able to use `window.opener.loaction`from the child which unfortunately I am unable to do.

I have found a way that works, buuuuuuuut it's really nasty. I just have the parent window keep checking to see if the child window is there. Here is the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/ex9e7uLq/

Thanks to Eclecticist for sticking with me on this one too!

Comment: So you just want to refresh the parent window?  You could try `location.reload()` instead of `window.loaction = ...`.

Comment: Well, I need to redirect the parent window to a new location. However, it is interesting that location.reload() seems to be working fine, so thanks for the suggestion. However, I need a redirect too. So, reload is working fine, but anything I've tried to redirect seems to be failing.

Comment: I'm on a tablet atm, so I can't test this. I think it may be a possibility that `window` is referring to the currently open child window, so your initial redirect is actually trying to redirect the child page as it closes. You might be able to create a global var to refer to the parent window, or perhaps create a custom event.

Comment: Something else to try is `location.replace()` .

Comment: Well, I've tried creating a global var to use. Still nothing. As a test I had it alert out it's location and it was the parent window and not the child's location. I also tried location.replace() with the same result. I appreciate your help on this. I'm just at a loss as to why it is not working.

Comment: Odd.  I'll toy with it on my own webserver tonight (6-7 hours from now) and see if I come up with something.  If you do happen to figure out what it is, please answer your own question so I'm not smashing my face against a keyboard for nothing :) .

Comment: Oh, so I think I found a really nasty/unclean way to do it. Here is the fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/ex9e7uLq/ . Again, this is not ideal since it is checking to see if the window is open every so often, but at least the stupid redirect works. Any thoughts? Again, you da man!

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this on Chrome, Firefox, and IE all with no problems.  Here is an [example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fepacihifimo/1/).

```
var win = window.open("http://www.google.com");

var winClosed = setInterval(function () {

    if (win.closed) {
        clearInterval(winClosed);
        location.assign("http://www.bing.com/");
    }

}, 250);
```

From your question, I know you wanted to attach an event handler to the child window.  However, while testing different methods to do just that, I ran across a plethora of problems.  Generally, Internet Explorer would fail to register any event in the child window from the parent window.  Firefox and Chrome would act as if the event fired (regardless of the type) as soon as the child window launched.

I've read other SO questions with answers that apparently worked by doing what you want, but personally could not get them to work.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var new_window = window.open('courseAddress.php');

var intr = setInterval(function(){
  console.log(new_window.closed);
  if(new_window.closed){
    clearInterval(intr);
    window.location='http://www.google.com';
  }
}, 200);
```

Comment: Give some more details